# Memcache and Eventual consistency

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working on a small project to learn about Google App Engine, the project is in Java and has Customer objects,
instances of Customer can have a policy.  Each customer is in its own entity group so that transactions can be used to
modify the customer.

The main page of the site is a list of Customers, when a new customer is added the customer list is displayed again.

Since each customer is in their own entity group there are times when the newly added customer does not appear in the
new customer list, refreshing the customer list after a few seconds and the customer will appear.   A similar problem
exists when deleting customers, you delete the customer but it appears in the overall list for a few seconds.   I understand
that this is to be expected in Google App Engine because of the eventual consistency that the datastore provides.

So I've tried to get around this problem by using memcache to store the customers that have been recently added or recently
deleted.  The code I'm using is below.

```
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    List<Customer> cachedCustomers = myCache.getCached();
    List<Customer> recentlyDeleted = myCache.getDeleted();
    // Calls the real datastore.
    List<Customer> dbCustomers = customerDao.getCustomerList();
    Set<Customer> allCustomers = new HashSet<Customer>();

    //  Add cached first as these are most the most up todate.
    allCustomers.addAll(cachedCustomers);
    allCustomers.addAll(dbCustomers);
    allCustomers.removeAll(recentlyDeleted);

    List<Customer> allList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    allList.addAll(allCustomers);
    Collections.sort(allList);        
    return allList;
}
```

I'm asking here because I think that the way I'm going about this does not feel the 'right' way to do it and would like
to hear from those who know better ways to get around the issues that eventual consistency creates.

Comment: Why do you need to put each customer in a different entity group? What transactions are you doing on customer? If you really need the list of customers to be always up to date, this means that they should be in the same entity group. Just define the entity groups based on what you want to see. Also, if customers are related to a single user, you can make the hierarchy user -> customers and than make a query using user as ancestor. This query will return the most up to date results.

Comment: There is a performance restriction that prevents too many updates per second per entity.  This page http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention.html describes it.  I've each customer is in its own entity group, customers so I can modify the customers policies etc within a transaction.

Comment: Yes, there is a limit of approx 1 update/sec in entity groups, but are you sure you will surpass this limit? You will have to give more info about your models for people to help you. If customers belong to a single user, you can have the hierarchy User -> Customer -> Policy without any problem.

Comment: By putting all the customers into one entity group the entire site can only handle one update per second.  That would be much too slow.  The Customers don't belong to users so I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is what [the docs recommends](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/overview.html#Usage_Notes). So I believe it is the right way to do it.

Also, I made a Google and GitHub search for a library that could handle that for you but couldn't find it. So for this way of caching recent insertions and deletions feel more 'right', I would suggest you to write a library that handles this for any persistent class you want.

For an extra, I suggest reading [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/ikai%2420eventually%2420consistent/google-appengine/X8O2pDZt5i8/NrG3JOkjTUsJ) where Ikai Lan, the Developer Programs Engineer of Google App Engine, explains how fetches and insertions work in HR and what are the performance implications compared to the Master/Slave datastore.

Answer (score 0):

With HRD, in the 99.9% case the results of your write operation should be visible within seconds. So in a typical web application, if you serve a web page as a result of the operation, the time before the user performs the next operation should be sufficient to pick up the writes.

So if you generate the result page from the live data objects in the application, you should be fine. You should also be fine if you redirect the user to e.g. a customer page where you read the customer by ID (as that is consistent).

If you need to query, and you need the results to show up in a query issued directly after the operation, I think there's no way around either memcache, or using some tricks to record the presence/absence of just modified objects.